# Is this normal hard drive noise?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

I recently replaced my PC's hard drive with a [Hitachi GST Deskstar 7K2000 HDS722020ALA330](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822145298) and it makes so much noise that I want to replace it again. I re-read the reviews for this drive expecting to see people complaining about the noise but I didn't see much in that regard, this makes me wonder.... is this normal?

Please listen to the audio in the following YouTube video. MovieMaker made my add a video or image so I grabbed a photo that was on my desktop. It's a laptop, that is NOT the system I'm talking about.
https://youtu.be/6cglrQouqdo

WMIC reports status:

> OK

CrystalDiskInfo also [claims all is well](http://spireon.d.pr/DM42/4vrOQ7y9)

If this is normal, is there a specification that addresses "operation noise"? How can I purchase a drive that is quiet (without going SSD)?

Comment: Why'd you down-vote me? What's wrong with the question? Speak up, Anon!

Comment: Tested in another machine? or via a usb adaptor on another machine

Comment: My bad for posting in the wrong site, question posted in super user in case anyone is interested: http://superuser.com/questions/1135558/is-this-normal-hard-drive-noise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a drive that is resetting it's head often. Please check the smart attributes on the drive to see if it's indicating a health issue and if so, replace the drive. Generally they shouldn't be making that sort of noise.

That said, a SSD is likely a great solution, as they're getting a lot cheaper, a modern 250 gb drive could be had for under $100 new.

Comment: WMIC reports "OK", CrystalDiskInfo also reports everything is fine: http://spireon.d.pr/DM42/4vrOQ7y9.

Comment: That's weird. So certain review sites will sometimes to audio tests. In this case, Tom's Hardware did one, http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/HDD-6Gbit,2528-9.html

Comment: As you can see, that drive was actually fairly low in the pack. If you can return it, do so and get another one, as that one is super suspect.